# What stacks with Cavalier Challenges

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, multi-classing

What (if any) are abilities, feats, or classes that stack or help progress with the Cavalier class's Challenge ability.

To a lesser degree I guess I am also looking at the Samurai which also gets the same Challenge stacking but the main focus is Cavalier.

I am looking for any abilities, or character options that progress any aspect of the challenge (excluding Order modifications from your chosen Order). Such as uses per day, increased effectiveness, etc.

Comment: We try to stick to a one post, one question format. Someone might be able to answer only part of your question, not both, or we might get conflicting answers that are both half right otherwise. I recommend you ask your secondary question separately or simply [review the rules on Alternate Classes](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/).

Comment: Alright. I'll edit and remove the additional question.

Comment: Are you only interested in the bonus damage all cavaliers get, or have you selected an Order? Including all orders in the question would be for too broad to answer with specifics.

Comment: Excluding Order abilities as those are part of the cavalier class, looking for features/options outside of the standard class. I am mostly looking for ways to gain additional uses per day or stack progression with other classes, but extra damage would fall under the interest of this question.